# golang recursive function how to check return?

Tags: go

Learning golang, proect euler problem 5. I was messing around with a recursive function and I could not figure out a way to get the return value to be correct.

In go I cannot take out the return at the end of the `five()` function and I also cannot get it to return the right value to execute the if statement in the `main()` function...

I realize I can do this without the recursion but I would like to know how to do it with recursion if possible.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"os"
)

func recursive(num int, div int) int {

    if div == 1 {
        fmt.Println(num)
        return num
    }
    switch num % div {
    case 0:
        recursive(num, div-1)
    default:
        return -1
    }
    return num
}

func main() {
    for i := 20; ; i += 20 {
        if recursive(i, 19) == 1 {
            fmt.Println("finished")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `return recursive(num, div-1)`?

Comment: I believe it should also be:
    if div == 1 {
        return 1    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, and besides the comments above, it should also break once the answer is found.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"os" 
)

func recursive(num int, div int) int {
    if div == 1 {
         return 1
    }
    switch num % div {
    case 0:
        return recursive(num, div-1)
    default:
        return -1
    }
    return num
 }

 func main() {
    for i := 120; ; i += 20 {
        if recursive(i, 19) == 1 {
            fmt.Printf ("finished with %v\n", i)
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes I was missing the return, I had commented out the `os` import because I was going to use `os.Exit(0)`.